# ngFor is not working for an array

Tags: angular, ngfor

Here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from '../../services/project';
import { Project } from '../../models/project';

@Component({
    selector: 'projects-component',
    template: `
        <pre>{{ projects | json }}</pre>
        <span>I WORK</span>
        <span *ngFor="let project of projects"> here: {{ project | json }} </span>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./style.css']
})
export class ProjectsComponent {

    projects: Project[];

    constructor(
        private projectService: ProjectService
    ) {
        this.projectService.projects().then((projects) => {
            this.projects = projects;
            console.log('Projects:',this.projects);
        });
    }
}
```

That prints the following:

[image]

`<span *ngFor="let project of projects"> here: {{ project | json }} </span>` is supposed to print each project but it isn't, I suspected at first that there might some css being applied to the `<span>` tag so I added that `<span>I WORK</span>` to make sure that nothing suspicious is happening and there isn't.

What am I missing from my code to get the *ngFor working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSON you have given, seems this.projects has another object named projects. you need

```
 <span *ngFor="let project of projects.projects"> here: {{ project  }} </span>
```

also no need of **`|json`** pipe